My cx_Freeze is giving an error. How do I fix this problem?
I am trying to create an executable for my game, but it gives an error every time I try to start it. How can I fix it? I noticed that it might be the PNG image; the image is 320x32, and I don't know if that influences it. Please help me! T-T
The error:
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
C:\Users\com\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareF
oundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
ages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\_startup
_. py", line 141, in run
module_init.run(f" __ main_{name}")
File
"C:\Users\com\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareF
oundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
ages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\console.p
y", line 25, in run
exec(code, main_globals)
File "DinoGame.py", line 27, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory:
'C:\Users\com\DinoGame\build\exe.win-amd64-3.11\lib\li
brary.zip\Dino\Spritesheet.png'.

And this is my setup.py:
import cx_Freeze
import os

executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable(
        script="DinoGame.py",  
        base="Win32GUI"  
    )
]
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["pygame", "os", "random"],
    "include_files": [
        (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Dino"), "Dino"),  
        (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Musicas"), "Musicas")  
    ],

}
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="DinoGame",
    version="1.0",
    description="Jogo Dino feito por Gustavo Carvalho",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executables
)

I tried changing the image folder, like moving the image to the Music folder, but the problem (ERROR) followed the image. I tried other codes for my setup.py, but it still didn't work. I also tried changing parts of my game related to the image or the image folder, and it still didn't work, and the error persisted.
